# Break long {% with %} assignment into multiple lines in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, with-statement, code-readability

I'd like to improve my Django's template readability by breaking a very long `{% with ... %}` multi-assignment tag into multiple lines (without having to use multiple `% with %` tags).

I have a very long `{% with ... %}` statement in my code (3 assignations), and it'd be nice if I could break it into multiple lines, but every combination I try ends in a

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /products/
Invalid block tag on line 132: 'endwith'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

In order words, I have this:

```
{% with is_ratable=is_ratable|default:False|logical_or:product.is_ratable is_heartable=is_heartable|default:False|logical_or:product.is_heartable is_customizable=is_customizable|default:False|logical_or:product.is_customizable %}
```

and I'd like to break it into something like

```
{% with is_ratable=is_ratable|default:False|logical_or:product.is_ratable 
        is_heartable=is_heartable|default:False|logical_or:product.is_heartable
        is_customizable=is_customizable|default:False|logical_or:product.is_customizable
%}
```

Is it possible? I'm using Django 2.0.3 and Python 3.6.5

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should simply *not* write such logic in the template, this is business logic, this belongs in the *view*.

Comment: It's not possible. Template tags must start and end at the same line.

Comment: Thank you @thebjorn And you're right. It is a duplicate. Dang... I swear I searched before posting mine.

Comment: @BorrajaX no prob. We all run into this one at some point ;-)

Comment: @BorrajaX if you absolutely must do this, this hack[0] worked for me for many years in Django 1.X, though I haven't had a need to try it in 2.X.

[0] http://zachsnow.com/blog/2016/multiline-template-tags-django/